# How to have specific htaccess rules not to be applied in a specific folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess into my root directory. However I want it to be applied anywhere EXCEPT the `admin` dir.

How can I achieve this?

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Set XSS Protection header
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override those settings by putting a separate .htaccess file in the `admin` directory, setting `ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hours"` for example. Or if you have full access to the Apache config files you could use the `<Directory>` directive. (see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)

Comment: How can I just not use any cache in the admin directory?

Comment: Just the one line in the .htaccess in the admin directory `ExpiresActive Off`, that will send no expires headers.